# Serialize a form without submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Is there a way to achieve serialization without calling the submit function for an ajax call? I've checked everywhere and can seem to find a decent answer for this particular problem. This is a java script function called when I click a button within the form.

```
document.forms[FORMNAME].submit();
```

Instead :

```
var form = $(document.forms[FORMNAME]);

$.ajax({
  type     : "POST",
  url      : form.attr('action'),
  data     : form.serializeArray(),
  success : function(data) {
    console.log("2");
  },
  error : function() {
    console.log("3");    
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log("4");
  }
});
```

I get this error when I run.

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.attr is not a function
```

I also tried this.

```
var form = $(document.forms[FORMNAME]);

        $.ajax({
         type     : "POST",
         url      : $(form).attr('action'),
         data     : $(form).serialize(),
         success  : function(data) {
         console.log("2");
         },
         error    : function() {
         console.log("3");

         },
         complete : function() {
         console.log("4");
         }
        });
```

I really get my form when I do this `$(document.forms[FORMNAME])`.

Seems to only work when I work with this, but this is not what I want.

```
document.forms[FORMNAME].submit(function(event){

        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        //AJAX STUFF
     });
```

Comment: Of course there is, just call `$(form).serialize()` anywhere, and you'll get the serialized form ?

Comment: @adeneo It does not work. I also tried the $(form).

Comment: Well, you need a selector that actually targets the form, like an iD

Comment: @adeneo I got my selector. $(document.forms[FORMNAME]); I get the form.

Comment: If `form` is indeed a valid jQuery object - regardless of whether it contains your form or not - `form.attr` should definitely be a function: hence, `form` is either being overwritten before you log to console, or you have a conflict such that `$` is not a reference to jQuery. You should not have to wrap it again, using `$(form)` as in your second example. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42q9ry1w/) to show your code should work.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I know it should... but it doesn't I'm so confuse.

Comment: @fneron: Well, if we can take all of your code and reproduce it in a setting where it works as you've intended, that tells us that the error is not to be found within the code you've posted. I've already mentioned a few of the possible causes of error, but whatever it is, it's difficult for us to give you much more help when we don't have access to whichever part of the code contains the error.

Comment: @DavidHedlund As a matter of fact, jQuery was not loaded. I believed it was window.$, but when I ran window.jQuery. Well you know the rest. thanks. I still wonder why I could call all those function on submit function without jQuery...

Comment: Well, `document.forms[FORMNAME].submit(...)` would call the native `submit` function on the form node. Regardless of whether or not jQuery was present, because `document.forms[FORMNAME]` is never a jQuery object, so `.submit` will always submit the form, never add a listener. As for `$`, it may have collided with other frameworks. Prototype, for instance, also uses `$`.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Right on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Use to avoid Uncaught TypeError: form.attr is not a function

```
$(form).attr('action')
```

And for serialize form data use

```
$(form).serialize()
```

Comment: This is exacly what I believe I need to do, but if you check my code. It doesn't work. I also changet form to $(form) in the ajax call...

Comment: jQuery was strangely not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can call $( "form" ).serialize(); anywhere and it will serialize the values and will return a string, provided there is a name attribute attached to every input element.

HTML

```
<form id = "someForm">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name ="name"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Surname</td><td><input type="text" name="sur"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>DOB</td><td><input type="date" name="date"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan="2">
         <button type = "button" id ="serForm">Serialize Form </button>
         </td>
     </tr> 
    </table>
</form>
<div id="sitVal"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#serForm").on('click',function(){
  var serializeVal = $( "form" ).serialize();
  $("#sitVal").text(serializeVal);
})
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/swpfuo7v/1/)

**NOTE:** This is just for demo you can change as required